# Question about a notation of line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

If $C$ is a complex Riemann Surface with positive genus,  $D$ a divisor on $C$, $L$ a line bundle of $C$, with the term $L(D)$ what do we mean?

I have this idea:
$L(D)$ set of all sections of $L$ with poles on $D$. So it makes sense to define the exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow L(D) \rightarrow L \rightarrow L/L(D) \rightarrow 0$$ where $L/L(D)$ is the set of all sections of $L$ modulo those with poles on $D$.

Comment: $0 \to L(D) \to L \to L/L(D) \to 0$ doesn't make any sense. I think what you mean is the following: $0 \to L \to L(D) \to L(D)/L \to 0.$

Comment: For the definition of $\mathcal O_C(D)$ and $L(D),$ you can look at 14.2.2 and 14.2.J in the following note: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjan2915public.pdf (*Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, Ravi Vakil,* January 2015 Version)